# Encrypt traffic with VpnService

Tags: android, security, encryption, vpn

I've searched for a solution for 2 days.
The problem is: i need to create the app for `encrypting` (with some custom algorithm) all internet traffic from a device.
I've found that I can use vpn and android provides me a class `VpnService`. I don't understand how to encrypt the tcp packets with `VpnService` class.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

By using VpnService, you can get all the IP packet routed to your interface.
What you get here, is IP packet, which takes TCP/UDP packet as payload.
The the IP packet should be tunneled to remote server.
Encrypt the traffic with remote server is what you need.